# XmlAdapter is ignored by Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

We are using Spring Boot for our project. One of my JAXB class is as below:

```
        @XmlRootElement(name = "Test"
        public class Test {

            @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
            @XmlElementName(name = "test", required = false)
            private Map < String, Object > test = mew HashMap < String, Object > ();
            .....

        }
```

`TestAdapter.java` simply extends the `javax.xml,bind.annotation.adapters.XMLAdapter` and overrides the `marshal()` and `unmarshal()` methods. For some reason, the `marshal()` and unmarshal() methods are not being called. What could be the reason? Do I need to do anything extra here? Why my `XMLAdapter` is ignored by Spring Boot? Any idea?

Comment: And is should be used because? What is using this, what is exposing this as XML.

Comment: @M.Denium I kindly request you to elaborate the question.

Comment: Why should Spring Boot use JAXB? There isn't much more to it. What makes you think that the API you are exposing (assuming Spring MVC here) should use JAXB for XML marshalling?

Comment: @M.Denium We are able to get the proper response for most of the endpoints except where XmlAdapter is used.

Comment: Again, show the endpoints/api that is using this. Also make sure that jaxb is being used and that you are not using Jackson (delibarate or not) to do marshalling.

Comment: @M.Deinum. My apologies.we are using Jackson. Actually I am working on a migration project . How to make XmlJavaTypeAdapter work with Jackson? Any other solution if doesn't work?

Comment: You don't as that is Jackson and not JAXB. So trying to use JAXB technology with Jackson isn't going to work. You will have to use Jackson converters for that or stop using Jackson and use JAXB for the marshalling.

Comment: @M.Denim Thanks for the clarification. Can you provide some example for my scenario using Jakson? Any website link is also appreciated.

Comment: Well if it were for JSON I could, not for the XML part. You did include the `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` dependency? I believe that includes an adapter which would be automatically applied, although I have no experience with that.

Comment: @M.Denium  I have not included `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`. Do you want me to include that?

Comment: Well if you want jackson to understand the annotations than you have to use that, else it will be ignored. But why are you using Jackson to create XML while you are using JAXB annotations?

Comment: This is a migration project and someone just left the JAXB annotations like that . For some reason, much of the code is working fine, but XmlAdapter is somehow not working. Then just now realised that it won't work after your clarification.

Comment: It actually never worked the annotations where just ignored.